# generic list of objects contains short returning false

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-4.0

I am working on a project and i have to check for some values of type short in a generic list of object. Strangely I noticed that it is always returning false even if there is that value in the generic list of objects. I am providing a small piece of code which replicates that scenario in my project.

```
List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
objectList.Add(1);
objectList.Add(2);
objectList.Add(3);
if (objectList.Contains(1))
{
    short i = 1;
    if (objectList.Contains(i))
    {
    }
    else if (objectList.Contains(i.ToString()))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //Entering this else this loop only
    }
}
```

My assumption is because of the difference in the size for those types it may be returning false. Any other thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer: You add Int32 (int), and look for Int16 (short)

Comment: I am adding into an object list not an integer generic list. Also your explanation makes sense for the first look at the else if statement too..i am converting to string and checking

Comment: Your list is `List<object>` and contains boxed Int32. You're looking for short or string. It doesn't contains both. It contains only int.

Comment: Checking will help only if you will use foreach loop, and convert each element in list and compare. Now you're converting input, not elements in list.

Answer (score 3):

```
objectList.Add(1);
```

is the same as

```
int i = 1;
objectList.Add(i);
```

So

```
int y = 1;
objectList.Contains(y); // true

short z = 1;
objectList.Contains(z); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding boxed Integer objects to the list, then seeing if a boxed short or string version of the number is in the list, both of which are going to be false because they're different types.

Try casting your short to an int in the first test. Why did you choose to not use generic `<int>` and skip the boxing/unboxing?

Comment: That is what I have done, I converted to int and it returned to true. The integer values I am adding from an enumeration in my code and am looking to compare with the property value of an entity, which is a small int in the database. I was moving an old code and have added the same code. I should have considered generic int instead of object may be to eliminate boxing and unboxing. Thanks hatchet.

Answer (score 0):

short is an object type so by default it would only be equal to it's own instance. This equality has been overriden inside the framework as such:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (!(obj is short))
    return false;
  else
    return (int) this == (int) (short) obj;
}
```

Not how you and me would have expected it :)

It is even more unexpected than you would think. Take the following cases:

```
int i = 1;
short s = 1;
System.Console.WriteLine(i==s ? "Yes" : "No"); // Yes
System.Console.WriteLine(i.CompareTo(s)==0 ? "Yes" : "No"); // Yes
System.Console.WriteLine(s.CompareTo(i) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No"); // ERROR !
System.Console.WriteLine(s.Equals(i) ? "Yes" : "No"); // No
System.Console.WriteLine(i.Equals(s) ? "Yes" : "No"); // Yes
```

Not very consistent en predicatable

Comment: It's consistent if you study C#'s rules for implicit conversion of some value types, as well as the method signatures of CompareTo and Equals.

Comment: No it doesn't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx --> x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).

Comment: Thanks guys. Your observations are really helpful.

Comment: I agree that on the face, it looks like they break their own guidelines. But implicit conversions are a special case. In reality, i.Equals(s) does not actually happen. It is converted by the compiler to the equivalent of i.Equals((int)s), so it's not actually breaking the rules of Equals since ((int) s).Equals(i) does give the same result as i.Equals((int) s).

Comment: Yes the implicit (widening) conversion from short to int is the explanation of why it returns what it does. It does the conversion because there is a method int.equals(int) and no int.equals(short). Since you can't tell if such a method is or isn't there I made the statement that it's not very predictable (it is explainable though)