# Equals versus == when comparing a double to zero

Tags: c#, double, equality

I'm trying to compare a double value to see if it is equal to zero. The following will work:

```
Assert.IsTrue(0d==0);
```

However this will fail:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Equals(0d,0));
```

I think the second argument (0) is being treated as an integer. However, I don't understand why Equals(0d, 0) evaluates as false whereas 0d==0 is true. It can't be rounding because both values are directly input as zeros.

Comment: "I'm trying to compare a double value" - but you are comparing `decimal` to `int`

Comment: @Henk: I'm not following your line of thought here. Where is the decimal?

Comment: No, you're right. Tripped over that m/d postfix again.

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively it's as easy as "they're not both doubles".

If you want to go in depth however, `Object.Equals` (the static method you call in your second example) is this:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
{
    return ((objA == objB) || (((objA != null) && (objB != null)) && objA.Equals(objB)));
}
```

The 2 references are not equal, neither is `null`, so `Double.Equals` gets called virtually:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is double))
    {
        return false;
    }
    double d = (double) obj;
    return ((d == this) || (IsNaN(d) && IsNaN(this)));
}
```

The argument is not a `double` so it returns `false`.

This is taken from `mscorlib` for .NET 4.0 64-bit.

Comment: I gets a lot more 'interesting' if you also include Compare implementations. int.CompareTo(double) does not give you the same result as double.CompareTo(int). If you think hard you can explain all the cases but then you have to take into account implicit conversions (can do an implicit conversion from int to double but not from double to int). My advice is to always ensure that you compare on values of the same number type by doing explicit casts or conversions

Comment: See also my answer and the comments (int vs short) on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780002/generic-list-of-objects-contains-short-returning-false

Answer (score 2):

I believe Equals(0d,0) may be doing a type comparison also.  0d is not technically equal to 0 because they are not same type.

Edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

This is the case it seems.

MSDN: true if the specified Object is equal to the current Object; otherwise, false.

Alternatively you could to something like Convert.ToDouble(0) and it should work.  I'm not near a C# compiler right now so I can't check if that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line the == operator casts the values to a common type, while in the second the **Double.Equals** method is called as a result, and it before comparing does a type-check which returns false, as one value is a **double** and the other is an **integer**.